# Combining probability percentages or fractions

Tags: probability

If I have a bag with 4 different color marbles, one of the colors being green, then I am assuming that the chance of drawing the green marble on the first attempt would be 1/4 or 25% or 3 to 1 against. Is this correct?

What I am trying to find out is how can I calculate the % (or fraction) chance of drawing a green marble at least once in 2 tries. if the first attempt is unsuccessful then the the marble is placed back in the bag so that the second attempt will also be 1/4 chance.

Do i need to add or multiply 1/4 (or .25) in order to figure out the chance of drawing the green marble at least once in 2 attempts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

If $p$ is the probability that *both* tries are unsuccesful then $1-p$ is the probability that at least one of the tries is succesful. So finding $p$ is enough here. Can you do that?

Comment: No I can't. To me it sounds like the same question I asked but backwards. I would say that the chance of 1 non-successful try would be 3/4. So do I need to multiply 3/4 x 2 or multiply 3/4 x 3/4 or add 3/4 + 3/4 to find p?

Comment: Ok I think I got it... so something like 1 - (.75  x .75) = .4375     so the answer would be about 44% of getting a green marble on at least 1 of the 2 attempts. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. That is correct. If questions are asked with "at least" or "at most" in it then quite often it is handsome to look for the probability of the complement.